# already exists in stack arn:aws:cloudformation: S3 bucket

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-serverless

When trying to deploy a service in API gateway, I get this error:

> already exists in stack arn:aws:cloudformation: S3 bucket

I tried to remove the API stack, and use unique names in another publication, I found information that the problem was in the function that called the event source, but I don’t know how to rewrite without using it.

What am I doing wrong?

```yaml
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs14.x
  stage: dev
  region: us-east-1

package:
  excludeDevDependencies: true
  individually: true


custom:
  fileUploadBucketName: ${self:service}-bucket-${self:provider.stage}

functions:
  uploadImage:
    handler: src/handlers/s3Handler.handler
    events:
      - s3:
          bucket: ${self:service}-bucket-${self:provider.stage}
          event: s3:ObjectCreated:*

resources:
  Resources:

    MyBucket:
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      Properties:
        BucketName: ${self:custom.fileUploadBucketName}
      DeletionPolicy: Retain
      UpdateReplacePolicy: Retain
      Metadata:
        'AWS::CloudFormation::DependsOn':
          - BucketNameParam
```